# Get Authors Role

Tags: users, user-roles, author-template

I am using the admin role and 2 custom roles. On the author.php i want to be able to place the role of that user.

I am using this to pull the role out in text

```
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$user_id = $curauth->ID;
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
        echo $role;
}
```

Put i want to be able to put that into something like

```
if (current_user_can('buyer')) { 
        get_template_part( 'buyer', 'edit' ); } 
      else if (current_user_can('courier')) { 
        get_template_part( 'courier', 'edit' ); } 
      else if (current_user_can('banned')) { 
        get_template_part( 'account', 'banned' ); }
      else if (is_user_logged_in()) { 
        get_template_part( 'account', 'error' );
    } else {  }
```

Which using for the current users, i need to make that work for the author user.

Comment: You question is a little confusing.  The first code echoes a user's role.  The second code adds a template part based on their role.  What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: The second code echos the current user, i want it to echo the author so i may use it in the author.php.

Comment: If my answer worked please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to "current_user_can" WordPress provides "[user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can)" which will take a User object or ID as a parameter.  Combining your top code and the bottom code with the new function it would look like this:

```
$author_user = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); // the queried object in 'author.php' should be an author user

if (user_can($author_user, 'buyer')) { 
  get_template_part( 'buyer', 'edit' );
} else if (user_can($author_user, 'courier')) { 
  get_template_part( 'courier', 'edit' );
} else if (user_can($author_user, 'banned')) { 
  get_template_part( 'account', 'banned' ); 
} else {
  // etc...
}
```